# Github desktop's text replacement is driving me nuts

Tags: github, github-desktop

Does anybody know how to permanently disable text replacement for the OS X version?
There doesn't seem to be a preference setting and it keeps on resetting back to enabled, which is crap.
It keeps on changing the world gson -> son for example.  Is the desktop still being maintained?

Or is there a better GUI client that I should try?

Comment: Might want to log a ticket with github on this, they are pretty responsive with their support tickets.